# Api Gateway connection to Event Bridge giving error. Eventbridge-PutEvents not supported

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, serverless, serverless-framework, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to create an event bridge connection via Serverless framework but getting EventBridge-PutEvents is not supported error.

```
# Create event bridge integration
    EventBridgeIntegration:
      DependsOn:
        - HttpApiRole
      Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
      Properties:
        ApiId: !Ref HttpApi
        Description: Event Bridge integration
        IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
        IntegrationSubtype: EventBridge-PutEvents        
        PayloadFormatVersion: 1.0
        CredentialsArn: !GetAtt HttpApiRole.Arn
        RequestParameters:
          Detail: $request.body.detail
          DetailType: $request.body.action
          Source: $request.body.source
          EventBusName: !GetAtt EventBus.Name
```

I am getting this error with above statement

Error:
CREATE_FAILED: EventBridgeIntegration (AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration)
Operation: EventBridge-PutEvents is not supported. (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException;

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. PayloadFormatVersion should be in quotes. This solved the issue for me.

```
PayloadFormatVersion: “1.0”
```